# MongoDB - mgo library (Golang) - Multiple insert/updates

Tags: optimization, go, mgo

Is there a way in the **Collection struct** to use **Upsert method for multiple documents** as it is with the **Insert method**? I would like to insert/update many documents at once for optimization purposes. Looking at the mgo API http://godoc.org/labix.org/v2/mgo I didn't find a way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not possible.

What you can do if you want to improve the connection utilization is to spawn a few goroutines and execute multiple upserts concurrently on the same session. They'll all block and receive results independently, but they'll all queue the requests to the server concurrently.